# I need help proving how to get $\cot x$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$
> { {\sin x \cos x} \over {(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)} } = \cot x
> $$

I need help proving that this equation is equal to $\cot x$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
(1+\cos(x))(1-\cos(x)) = 1 - \cos^2 (x)= \sin^2(x)
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: uhh I don't think so because I have to prove how to get that fraction to equal cotx and I have no clue what I am doing...

Comment: @kaylyn Try rewriting the denominator using what I showed you above and see if you can't get the left side to equal $\cos(x) / \sin(x)$, which is just the defintion of $\cot(x)$.